# A property of line bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a connected smooth proper $\mathbb{C}$-scheme. Let $L$ be a locally free $O_X$-module of rank 1 on $X$ with the property that for any locally free $O_X$-module $F$ of rank 1 on $X$, there exists an integer $n(F)$ such that $h^0(X, L^{\otimes n(F)}\otimes F)>0$ (note that we do not assume this holds for $n>n(F)$).

Is such $L$ necessarily ample? If not, do there exist connected smooth proper $\mathbb{C}$-schemes not admitting a sheaf with this property?

Comment: Take an ample line bundle $H$ an effective divisor $E$ such that $H+E$ is not ample, then it will have the property you state. For a definite example, let $X$ be the blow up of the projective plane at a point and $E$ the exceptional divisor. Let $H+E$ be the pull back of $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^2}(2)$.